# Make Y Axis Start at 0 in Charts

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

What I work with: C#, Windows Forms, Visual Studio 2010

This is what I do now

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCsKI.png)

This is what I want

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXEGg.png)

This is what's out now

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXNlc.png)

```
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize = 8;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelAutoFitMinFontSize = 8;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LineWidth = 2;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorTickMark.LineWidth = 2;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = montoMayor;
                        
            //chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = montoMenor;

            //if (montoMayor != montoMenor)
            //{
            //    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = montoMenor;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
            //}
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = true;
```

[review](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axisscalebreakstyle.startfromzero?view=netframework-4.8.1)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 90.1302d;
```

Here your 90.1302 is a variable, you should know better than me what 90.1302 stands for.

Here is my example:

```
chartArea.AxisY.Minimum = 0d;
```

[image]

```
chartArea.AxisY.Minimum = 90d;
```

[image]